# xpath - matching value of child in current node with value of element in parent

Tags: xpath, talend

Edit: I think I found the answer but I'll leave the open for a bit to see if someone has a correction/improvement.

I'm using xpath in Talend's etl tool. I have xml like this:

```
<root>  
 <employee>
  <benefits>
    <benefit>
      <benefitname>CDE</benefitname>
      <benefit_start>2/3/2004</benefit_start>
    </benefit>
    <benefit>
     <benefitname>ABC</benefitname>
     <benefit_start>1/1/2001</benefit_start>
    </benefit>
  </benefits>
<dependent> 
  <benefits>
    <benefit>
  <benefitname>ABC</benefitname>
 </benefit>
</dependent>
```

When parsing benefits for dependents, I want to get elements present in the employee's
benefit element.  So in the example above, I want to get 1/1/2001 for the dependent's
start date.  I want 1/1/2001, not 2/3/2004, because the dependent's benefit has benefitname ABC, matching the employee's benefit with the same benefitname.

What xpath, relative to /root/employee/dependent/benefits/benefit, will yield the value of
benefit_start for the benefit under  parent employee that has the same benefit name as the
dependent benefit name?  (Note I don't know ahead of time what the literal value will be, I can't just look for 'ABC', I have to match whatever value is in the dependent's benefitname element.

I'm trying:

../../../benefits/benefit[benefitname=??what??]/benefit_start

I don't know how to refer to the current node's ancestor in the middle of 
the xpath (since I think "." at the point I have ??what?? will refer to 
the benefit node of the employee/benefits.

EDIT: I think what I want is "current()/benefitname" where the ??what?? is.  Seems to work with saxon, I haven't tried it in the etl tool yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is malformed, and I don't think you've described your siduation very well (the XPath you're trying has a bunch of `../../`s at the beginning, but you haven't said what the context node is, whether you're iterating through certain nodes, or what.

Supposing the current context node were an `employee` element, you could select `benefit_start`s that match dependent benefits with

```
benefits/benefit[benefitname = ../../dependent/benefits/benefit/benefitname]
                                                                       /benefit_start
```

If the current context node is a `benefit` element in a `dependents` section, and you want to get the corresponding `benefit_start` for just the current `benefit` element, you can do:

```
../../../benefits/benefit[benefitname = current()/benefitname]/benefit_start
```

Which is what I think you've already discovered.

Comment: (+1) Good solution. Just a doubt: is this `current()`  a standard XPath function? (Or is it XLST or XQuery or other?)

Comment: @acdcjunior `current()` is part of XSLT. It's not in the XPath spec, which is a shame because it's very useful.